# Type WebServletContextListener cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: tomcat, servlets

[image]

[enter image description here][2]

My Tomcat version is 7.0 and My Servlet version is 3.0
Why I Don't have some Servlet 3.0's new feature?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+shift+o?

Comment: yes I used to import.

Comment: Can you check if the project facet was set to 3.x? Right click project -> properties -> project facets -> Dynamic web module >= 3

Comment: yes it's facet is  3.0